# Create Super Mario Mozaic Blendig Effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, blending

I am interested in creating a blending effect for a screen transition that takes the current view and pixelates the view and fades out.
The blueprint would be from Super Mario World on the Super Nintendo / Super Famicom.
I attached a YouTube video of this effekt. You can see it at 0:50 before "Mario Start" is shown.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naD6mNeHIsE

I wanted to implement this blending effect in an iOS game in Objective-C or Swift. That does not matter at the moment. I am interested in how this effect can be achieved.
Anyone got a hint or an idea?

Comment: Pick a transition filter: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-SW239

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done with next steps:

1) Take image that you want to mosaic
2) [Read it pixel data colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262893/881989)
3) Calculate average colors based on tile size
4) Draw tiles with average color on new image
5) Display new image
6) Change tile size and repeat from step 2)

I think this scenario with using `CoreGraphics` will have performance problems.

Another choice - use awesome [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) and `GPUImageMosaicFilter`. Check sample code - it have `GPUImageMosaicFilter` implemented.